# Unable to sign certificate for iOS app in Xcode 8.3.2

Tags: ios, xcode, certificate, xcode8

When I go to Xcode -> preferences -> accounts and select my account and "download all profiles" it doesn't update my iOS developer certificate so when I try to run the application on my phone it says the certificate has expired or been revoked.

I'm working on an app requiring Metal so I have to test it on my device and simulators aren't an option.

Any help on how to force this certificate to update?

Comment: Try downloading it from the developer.apple.com site perhaps...

Comment: if you don't need any of "capabilities", you can sign it "ad hoc" and use on your device. developers account is not required for that.

Answer (score 1):

Select automatic option from General Tab. It automatically create new certificate for you. [image: Follor the Image]

Answer (score 0):

**Xcode 8.x** versions are terrible. Save yourself some headaches by installing [Fastlane](https://fastlane.tools). It's free and open source.

Make sure you have the latest version of the Xcode command line tools installed:

```
xcode-select --install
```

Then Choose your installation method for example: Homebrew

```
brew cask install fastlane
```

Typically you'll use fastlane by triggering individual lanes:

```
fastlane [lane_name]
```

For your case you can run this command:

```
fastlane sign download_all
```

All your profiles will be downloaded and installed.

**NOTE**: You may want to empty your profile folder before running the fastlane command.

profiles are located at:

```
~/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles
```

If you'd like to take a look at a project already using fastlane check out [fastlane-examples](https://github.com/fastlane/examples) which includes **fastlane** setups. Also check out the new [fastlane docs](https://docs.fastlane.tools/)